# Change Codeigniter config variable permanently

Tags: codeigniter, variables, config

I have a problem with config variables, I'm using PHPMailer to send emails throught smtp, so I have to change config variables based my account info.

```
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.ipage.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'my_email@my_domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'my_password';
```

My account info are stored in database so when I put those info in email.php config file. The script work fine but when I change those from Controller the script do not work.

```
$this->config->load('email');
$this->config->set_item('smtp_user', $from); // $from $pass $host comes from db
$this->config->set_item('smtp_pass', $pass);
$this->config->set_item('smtp_host', $host);
$this->load->library('email');
```

When I delete variables from config file and I echo `$this->config` array, the variable are changed (from controller), but when I want to send the email it doesn't sent. it's like the variables are lost after some seconds, the email sent if variable are in config file.
So, I want to change those variable for a long time.

Comment: Where exactly, the mail configs are found? i.e in any file?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do exactly as the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) told you. First of all remove any `config/email.php` file. In your controller's action do like the following:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['smtp_user'] = $from; // $from $pass $host comes from db
$config['smtp_pass'] = $pass;
$config['smtp_host'] = $host;
$config['protocol']= 'smtp';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();
```